# Assigning shorcut keys in master page of vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working on vb.net application. In my master form in one tool strip menu item I am calling four forms together.

I want to give a shortcut key for this under a toolstrip menu item.

```
Dim frm As New frmKeyAssignBoard  
frm.Location = New Point(625, 0)   
frm.MdiParent = Me  frm.Show()
Dim frm1 As New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest  
frm1.Location = New Point(625, 225)  
frm1.MdiParent = Me
frm1.Show()

Dim frm2 As New FrmDelivary    
frm2.Location = New Point(965, 0) 
frm2.MdiParent = Me 
frm.show()
```

Etc.

Per example:

- if I press K, I want my cursor to go to the particular textbox of `frmKeyAssignBoard`
- if i press R i want to go my cursor the particular textbox of `FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest`
- if i press D i want to go my cursor the particular textbox of `FrmDelivary`

How can I do this?
i trey something like this in frmMaster_KeyDown event: but same page is showing again i have already open instance of FrmDelivary  ,so i don't want to show same page again . i want to just get cursor position to particular textbox of this form 
If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then  Dim form As New FrmDelivary  form.Show()
form.txtTicket.Focus()  Cursor.Position = form.txtTicket.Location
end if

Answer (score 0):

Based on your specific example, I think that this is a possible solution. Set the KeyPreview property in your master form to true, so that all key events are sent to the form KeyPressed event handler. Then, check if the key was pressed in that event handler. Once it is, you can use Cursor.Position to go to the location that you talked about.